# Swift UICollectionViewLayout contentSize crash

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Trying to adjust the content size of a collection view on 4" screens in iOS and I'm getting an error in the console about the width using collection view flow layout.

```
        if DeviceType.IS_4_INCH {
        collectionView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth - 50, height: collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height)
    }
```

Error:

```
The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is 
<UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fbb9144dd20>, and it is attached to 
<UICollectionView: 0x7fbb92885800; frame = (10 10; 270 750); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fbb914d25e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbb9147f560>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {325, 750}> collection view layout: 
<UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fbb9144dd20>.
```

I see the issue is relating to content size (325) when the frame is 270 but when I try to change it based on the screen width it crashes.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout like func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    if DeviceType.IS_IPAD_PRO || DeviceType.IS_IPAD {
        return CGSize(width: width / 3, height: 100)
    }
    else {
        return CGSize(width: width / 3, height: 100)

    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your elements exceeds the size of your UICollectionView after you resize frame

Try invalidating the current layout before reloading your data:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```